# MS SQL URL Encoded XML Reading Child Node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i need some help for reading the value of a node xml in ms sql.

The table looks like

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wppSt.png)

the settings column has the datatype "xml"

i want to read out some information with an sql query inside the xml column.

The problem is the format inside the xml see here:

```
<FCProfile version="5.1.0.1" fpid="142" fid="5" guid="e24fb72b-fc8f-435b-8b33-562a018d64e5" name="Vertrieb-IF FCO" type="Custom" useIndexFilter="true" fGuid="2ce5d088-509d-4bef-acc2-5d1dd79607a7">
  <IndexFilters>
    <SearchFilter format="Extended" operation="And">
      <ExtendedStatement>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;QueryBuilderSettings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://dev.docuware.com/settings/web/querybuilder"&gt;
  &lt;Root&gt;
    &lt;Operation&gt;And&lt;/Operation&gt;
    &lt;Conditions xsi:type="Condition"&gt;
      &lt;DBName&gt;ARCHIV&lt;/DBName&gt;
      &lt;Provider xsi:type="TextConditionProvider"&gt;
        &lt;Operation&gt;Equal&lt;/Operation&gt;
        &lt;Value&gt;Vertrieb&lt;/Value&gt;
        &lt;SystemFunction&gt;None&lt;/SystemFunction&gt;
      &lt;/Provider&gt;
    &lt;/Conditions&gt;
    &lt;Conditions xsi:type="GroupCondition"&gt;
      &lt;Operation&gt;Or&lt;/Operation&gt;
      &lt;Conditions xsi:type="Condition"&gt;
        &lt;DBName&gt;DOKUMENTART&lt;/DBName&gt;
        &lt;Provider xsi:type="TextConditionProvider"&gt;
          &lt;Operation&gt;Equal&lt;/Operation&gt;
          &lt;Value&gt;Baukasse&lt;/Value&gt;
          &lt;SystemFunction&gt;None&lt;/SystemFunction&gt;
        &lt;/Provider&gt;
      &lt;/Conditions&gt;
      &lt;Conditions xsi:type="Condition"&gt;
        &lt;DBName&gt;DOKUMENTART&lt;/DBName&gt;
        &lt;Provider xsi:type="TextConditionProvider"&gt;
          &lt;Operation&gt;Equal&lt;/Operation&gt;
          &lt;Value&gt;Anzahlungsrechnung (ausgehend)&lt;/Value&gt;
          &lt;SystemFunction&gt;None&lt;/SystemFunction&gt;
        &lt;/Provider&gt;
      &lt;/Conditions&gt;
      &lt;Conditions xsi:type="Condition"&gt;
        &lt;DBName&gt;DOKUMENTART&lt;/DBName&gt;
        &lt;Provider xsi:type="TextConditionProvider"&gt;
          &lt;Operation&gt;Equal&lt;/Operation&gt;
          &lt;Value&gt;Sonderrechnung&lt;/Value&gt;
          &lt;SystemFunction&gt;None&lt;/SystemFunction&gt;
        &lt;/Provider&gt;
      &lt;/Conditions&gt;
    &lt;/Conditions&gt;
  &lt;/Root&gt;
&lt;/QueryBuilderSettings&gt;</ExtendedStatement>
    </SearchFilter>
  </IndexFilters>
  <GeneralRights>General_Search, General_DisplayDocument, General_Export</GeneralRights>
  <AnnotationRights>Annotation_New</AnnotationRights>
  <FieldRights>
    <FieldRight right="Field_Modify" />
    <FieldRight right="Field_Read">
      <Fields>,KUNDE,AUFTRAG,MASCHINEN,DOKUMENTART,DOKUMENTDATUM,BETREFF,BEREICH,VORGANG,STATUS,DATEINAME,GESELLSCHAFT,HANDELSPARTNER,HANDELSPARTNERNR,PROJEKT,DOKUMENT_NR,ENDKUNDE,NAME_KONTAKT,BETRAG,ABTEILUNG,VERTRETER,ZEITRAUM_VON,ZEITRAUM_BIS,ARCHIV,ABGELEGT_VON,</Fields>
    </FieldRight>
    <FieldRight right="Field_Search">
      <Fields>,KUNDE,AUFTRAG,MASCHINEN,DOKUMENTART,DOKUMENTDATUM,BETREFF,BEREICH,VORGANG,STATUS,DATEINAME,GESELLSCHAFT,HANDELSPARTNER,HANDELSPARTNERNR,PROJEKT,DOKUMENT_NR,ENDKUNDE,NAME_KONTAKT,BETRAG,ABTEILUNG,VERTRETER,ZEITRAUM_VON,ZEITRAUM_BIS,ARCHIV,ABGELEGT_VON,</Fields>
    </FieldRight>
    <FieldRight right="Field_Write" />
  </FieldRights>
</FCProfile>
```

Some Parts are enclosed with "<" and ">" and some with "& lt;" and "& gt;"

The script i tried is:

```
select X.Y.value('(ExtendedStatement)[1]', 'VARCHAR(4000)') as SettingsText
from [dwsystem].[dbo].[DWFCProfile] e
OUTER APPLY e.settings.nodes('FCProfile/IndexFilters/SearchFilter') as X(Y)
where fid=5
```

but i want to read out only the "Value" in the"& lt;" Value "& gt;" Part Like:
Vertrieb, or Baukasse, or Anzahlungsrechnung

if i try something like this:

```
select X.Y.value('(Value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(4000)') as SettingsText
from [dwsystem].[dbo].[DWFCProfile] e
OUTER APPLY e.settings.nodes('FCProfile/IndexFilters/SearchFilter/ExtendedStatement') as X(Y)
where fid=5
```

I get a "NULL" Value.

I also tried this:

```
select cast(settings.value('(ExtendedStatement)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as xml).value('(FCProfile/IndexFilters/SearchFilter/ExtendedStatement/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Text
 FROM [dwsystem].[dbo].[DWFCProfile]
  where fid=5
```

I also get a "NULL" Value.

I found one interesting blog with my problem:

https://mcguirev10.com/2018/12/16/query-plaintext-or-encoded-xml-with-sql-server.html

but i can not get the solution.

Here you can see data from my database:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QWyu.png)

Would be great if someone could help me :)

//Edit

Now i tried the answer:
(Modified it by Column operation)

```
with xmlnamespaces (
  'http://dev.docuware.com/settings/web/querybuilder' as qb
)
select
  a.name as Benutzer,
  c.name as Gruppe,
  e.name as Rolle,
  i.name as Archivprofile,
  k.name as Archiv,
  Provider.value('(qb:Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value,
Provider.value('(qb:Operation/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Operation
from dbo.DWUser as a
left join dbo.DWUserToGroup b on b.uid=a.uid
left join dbo.DWGroup c on c.gid=b.gid
left join dbo.DWUserToRole d on d.uid=a.uid
left join dbo.DWGroupToRole j on j.gid=c.gid
left join dbo.DWRoles e on e.rid=j.rid
left join dbo.DWFCProfileToRole h on h.rid=e.rid
left join dbo.DWFCProfile i on i.fpid=h.fpid
left join dbo.DWFileCabinet k on k.fid=i.fid
outer apply i.settings.nodes('/FCProfile/IndexFilters/SearchFilter/ExtendedStatement') SearchFilter(ExtendedStatement)
outer apply (
  select cast(ExtendedStatement.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml) as EmbeddedXML
) Embedded
outer apply EmbeddedXML.nodes('/qb:QueryBuilderSettings/qb:Root/qb:Conditions/qb:Provider') as Conditions(Provider)
order by k.name;
```

this solution gives back only the first input value of the XML Node "Value"

Is it possible to get all inputs of "Value" from the data?

Like here in the XML you have fpid = 142 and fid = 5, there are 4 values of "value" (Vertrieb, Baukasse, Anzahlungsrechnung and Sonderrechnung).

```
 & lt;Value& gt;Vertrieb& lt;/Value& gt;
 & lt;Value& gt;Baukasse& lt;/Value& gt;
 & lt;Value& gt;Anzahlungsrechnung (ausgehend)& lt;/Value& gt;
 & lt;Value& gt;Sonderrechnung & lt;/Value& gt;
```

Here is a screenshot of the Database
[image: Database]

In the example the select schould give

4 times fpid = 142 and fid = 5 with value like(see above)
maybe in the xml column settings of fpid = 26 and fid = 5 there are 2 values in "value"
in fpid = 177 and fid = 5 there is only one value in "value" in the xml column

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you seem to have two problems here:

1. Embedded XML, and
2. Embedded XML with namespaces.

The elements you're trying to query in the embedded have a default namespace defined on the `QueryBuilder` element of `http://dev.docuware.com/settings/web/querybuilder`, so you'll need to reference that in your XPath query...

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  'http://dev.docuware.com/settings/web/querybuilder' as qb
)
select Provider.value('(qb:Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
from (
  select cast(ExtendedStatement.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml) as EmbeddedXML
  from dbo.DWFCProfile
  cross apply settings.nodes('/FCProfile/IndexFilters/SearchFilter/ExtendedStatement') SearchFilter(ExtendedStatement)
  where fid = 5
) Embedded
cross apply EmbeddedXML.nodes('/qb:QueryBuilderSettings/qb:Root/qb:Conditions/qb:Provider') as Conditions(Provider);
```

Because there are so many `left join`s involved in your extended query you can use `outer apply` instead of `cross apply` to allow rows to be returned even if some values might be null. So that looks like the following (untested, because I don't have your database available)...

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  'http://dev.docuware.com/settings/web/querybuilder' as qb
)
select
  a.name as Benutzer,
  c.name as Gruppe,
  e.name as Rolle,
  i.name as Archivprofile,
  k.name as Archiv,
  Provider.value('(qb:Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
from dbo.DWUser as a
left join dbo.DWUserToGroup b on b.uid=a.uid
left join dbo.DWGroup c on c.gid=b.gid
left join dbo.DWUserToRole d on d.uid=a.uid
left join dbo.DWGroupToRole j on j.gid=c.gid
left join dbo.DWRoles e on e.rid=j.rid
left join dbo.DWFCProfileToRole h on h.rid=e.rid
left join dbo.DWFCProfile i on i.fpid=h.fpid
left join dbo.DWFileCabinet k on k.fid=i.fid
outer apply i.settings.nodes('/FCProfile/IndexFilters/SearchFilter/ExtendedStatement') SearchFilter(ExtendedStatement)
outer apply (
  select cast(ExtendedStatement.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml) as EmbeddedXML
) Embedded
outer apply EmbeddedXML.nodes('/qb:QueryBuilderSettings/qb:Root/qb:Conditions/qb:Provider') as Conditions(Provider)
order by k.name;
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot :) just a short second question.I need to put this in a join
´´´
select a.name as Benutzer, c.name as Gruppe, e.name as Rolle, i.name as Archivprofile, k.name as Archiv, i."Value of ExtendedStament"
from DWUser as a
left join DWUserToGroup b on b.uid=a.uid
left join DWGroup c on c.gid=b.gid
left join DWUserToRole d on d.uid=a.uid
left join DWGroupToRole j on j.gid=c.gid
left join DWRoles e on e.rid=j.rid
left join DWFCProfileToRole h on h.rid=e.rid
left join DWFCProfile i on i.fpid=h.fpid
left join DWFileCabinet k on k.fid=i.fid
order by k.name
```

Comment: Short, you say? That's a lot of joins there. Give me a few minutes and I'll see what I can come up with...

Comment: :D Sorry 
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, would you have a look at my //Edit Post in the question? Maybe you have a solution for that:) Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is already 1 year and 5 months old, I would like to share my findings.
The difficulty is that the `DBNAME` nodes can be at different levels.
I took the approach of looking for them in the `EXTENDED STATEMENT` regardless of their level and then fetching the then associated information such as `OPERATION` and `VALUE` in addition in a recursive manner.

Additionally one must consider the `NAMESPACES` with the `EXTENDED STATEMENT`. Here I used the Asterisk (example : `*:Operation`) parameter, because I saw no other possibility than to circumvent the namespaces with this.
But then also `WITH XMLNAMESPACES (...)` is not really necessary - therefore i have commented it in the code.

(It is important to know that IF you use the XMLNAMESPACES, that you DON'T forget any namespace!).

Interestingly, I was looking for this solution myself for this "Docuware specific" problem and therefore ended up exactly with your question.

```
    --with xmlnamespaces (
    --  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd,
    --  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi,
    --  'http://dev.docuware.com/settings/web/querybuilder' as qb
    --)
    select A.fpid as PROFILE_ID
    ,A.fid as FILECABINET_ID
    ,A.name as PROFILE_NAME
    ,cast(ExtendedStatement.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml) as ESXML
    ,x.y.value('(../../@*:type)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Conditions_type
    ,x.y.value('(../../*:Operation)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Conditions_Operation
    ,x.y.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as DBName
    ,x.y.value('(../*:Provider/*:Operation)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Provider_Operation
    ,x.y.value('(../*:Provider/*:Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Provider_Value
    ,x.y.value('(../*:Provider/*:AddWildcard)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Provider_AddWildcard
    ,x.y.value('(../*:Provider/*:SystemFunction)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Provider_SystemFunction
    ,x.y.value('(../*:Provider/@*:type)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Provider_Type
    FROM [dwsystem].[dbo].[DWFCProfile] A
    OUTER APPLY A.settings.nodes('/FCProfile/IndexFilters/SearchFilter/ExtendedStatement') as SearchFilter(ExtendedStatement)
    outer apply (
    select cast(ExtendedStatement.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml) as EmbeddedXML
    ) Embedded
    outer apply EmbeddedXML.nodes('//*:DBName') as x(y)
    where A.type = 'DocuWare.Settings.FCProfiles.FCProfile, DocuWare.Settings'
```

Example Result
[image: Example Result]